# Using git rebase -i to squash commits on single branch, encountering merge conflicts

Tags: git

I've been asked to use git rebase -i to squash a set of 4-5 contiguous commits into 1 commit from a couple of weeks back. There have been some commits since then. So in the following diagram, I'd want to squash commits B through F into one commit:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I ...
    |               |
    - Want to squash-
```

I run

> git rebase -i 8007a14d

(where 8007a14d is A's hash), find the commits I want to squash, and close the file. But after closing, I'm asked to resolve several merge conflicts. Not being too familiar with the code past commit G, I decide to abort.

This seems a bit strange to me. I imagine git would replay the commits/diffs in the order they were committed in. As a sanity check, I tried a git rebase and left all commits as "pick", and I still got a merge conflict. Can someone help me make sense of this? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any merge commits within the history since `A`? Also, since you say that you are not familiar wih the code past `G`, you do realize that rebasing is generally not a good thing for an already published history, right? You shouldn’t rebase commits that were already pushed (and that includes squashing them). This will only cause problems for others later.

Comment: Also, what does the file look like just before you close it ?

Comment: You should not have merge conflicts. Perhaps a eol character problem...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I is chronologically latest on the branch

```
git checkout F
git reset --soft A # move pointer of branch to A, do not change content, all differences will be in index
git commit -m "Squashed stuff" # now you have a single revision after A that has a tree exactly like F
git cherry-pick F..I # replay everything after the squashed revisions
```

And now you are done.